# Maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have `num_locations` states,  where each state is of dimension encoded in  a vector `state_dims`. In the particular problem I'm solving, I have `num_locations = 1000`. When running the code:

```
value = np.zeros(tuple(num_locations))
for i in range(num_visits):
     value += utility[i].reshape(state_dims)
```

I get the error

```
Maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32
```

Is there a way to address this problem without using ndarrays (with lists,einsums, or similar objects)?

Comment: Why do you need so many dimension? Can't you use a flatten array. AFAIK, this constraint is fixed in the Numpy code for sake of performance. I hardly see a use-case where >32 dimensions can be useful. I mean, if each axis have at least 2 items, it means there is `2**33 = 8589934592 items`. Since items takes generally 4-8 bytes, this means one unique array will take at least 32-64 GiB of RAM...

Comment: do you really want a `1000d` array?  not an array of 1000 elements?  `valuws=no.zeros(1000)`

Comment: with a small `num_locations` (eg 3) show exactly what you are trying to do,  Hitting this 32 max is rare since few people need such a thing, and the memory required exceeds the RAM of most computers.